# SonarQube shows a security error in Spring Framework controllers and in Spring Framework Application main class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, sonarqube

Should I take this security warning seriously, this warning shows up in every controller

https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-4529

when I declare a controller like this

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/profile", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public UserProfile getUserProfile(String name) {
...
}
```

and this warning shows up in the application class

https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-4823

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should take security warnings seriously. At least for enterprise application.

If you have developed this application for learning something then it's totally your choice. Otherwise securing HTTP endpoint is best practice.

SonarQube **hotspot** rule is helping you to identify all such endpoints which show security vulnerability.