# SonarQube rule: "Using command line arguments is security-sensitive" in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube

SonarQube is just showing a Critical security issue in the very basic Spring Boot application. In the main method.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

SonarQube wants me to `Make sure that command line arguments are used safely here.`

I searched this on both StackOverflow and Google, and I am surprised that I couldn't find any single comment about this issue. I am almost sure that there are some security checks inside the `SpringApplication.run` method already. And also, I don't even remember that anyone sanitizes the main method arguments before calling `SpringApplication.run`. I simply want to tag it as **false positive** and move on.

Part of this question is also asked here: [SonarQube shows a secuirty error in Spring Framework controllers and in Spring Framework Application main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54856544/sonarqube-shows-a-secuirty-error-in-spring-framework-controllers-and-in-spring-f)

Is it false positive?

Comment: I haven't seen any instance of the args being sanitized in any of our boot apps. Dug a little into the usage of these args in the SpringApplication class. They are used to create SpringFactoriesInstances . So unless you are using the args variable to configure something in your app, you can choose to not set it (which would remove the error i guess)

Comment: @ArpanKanthal yeah me neither. I haven't seen anything like this before that people are sanitizing these values before calling Spring Boot run method. I tried to read the code Spring Boot quickly yesterday but wasn't able to dig deep enough to see something worth seeing. But still, I appreciate your comment. I will check it out deeper today. Thanks.

Comment: This rule is deprecated, and will eventually be removed. See: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-4823

Comment: The problem is when you actually are using one of these values. In my case I'm testing the arguments because I need to have two different ways of invoking the SpringBootApplication and I need to scan these values. Unfortunately, where I'm at, if there's any warnings in the least, it's deemed totally insecure with no ability to rationally evaluate it.

Answer (score 27):

If you are not using any command-line arguments ,then you could avoid mentioning the args parameter in the run method .Like the below code.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

}
```

This will remove sonarqube hotspot issue.

Answer (score 12):

If you are sure then you can include the following to get rid of the issue.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

}
```

It appears this is marked as a `security hotspot` as per sonar documentation. It states

> Unlike Vulnerabilities, Security Hotspots aren't necessarily issues that are open to attack. Instead, Security Hotspots highlight security-sensitive pieces of code that need to be manually reviewed. Upon review, you'll either find a Vulnerability that needs to be fixed or that there is no threat.

You can read more about it here [security hotspot](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/security-hotspots/)

As per this rule [RSPEC-4823](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-4823) or [S4823](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-4823), command line arguments are to be evaluated based on

- Any of the command line arguments are used without being sanitised
  first.
- Your application accepts sensitive information via command line
  arguments.

If your application falls into this category they are definitely a possible security issue to your application.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is a critical security issue indeed. It's just asking to sanitize the args before using it. There's no need for such a concern on a simple application, but it may be a big matter on a production application.

More details can be found on https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-4823?search=Make%20sure%20that%20command%20line%20arguments%20are%20used%20safely%20here.

Answer (score 0):

do not use command line paramters can fix this issue.

only for sonar check change code
from:

```
SpringApplication.run(ApiDispatchApplication.class, args);
```

to:

```
SpringApplication.run(ApiDispatchApplication.class);
```